# Find and Replace footer text in Word with an Excel VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, footer

I'm trying to make a *macro* in **Excel** which opens a **Word** document, find a especify text, which is inside of **footer** in word doc, and replace it for a text.

At the moment, my macro opens the word doc but I couldn't figure out how to get into footer and find those texts.

```
    Dim objWord
    Dim objDoc
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/NotaPromissoriaAutomatica.docx")
    objWord.Visible = True
```

The footer have two texts which have to be replaced

> 1 - VAR_CIDADE  > Which will be replaced the current city (which is in A1 of my excel table)
>   2 - VAR_DATA    > Which will be replaced the current date (which is in A2 of my excel table)

Comment: I think you can use Mail Merge into headers/footers which might be a ton easier...

Comment: It doesn't work as I want, I when I use mail merge, I can get the text from my excel table, but it doesn't update automatic, I don't know if I have to change any configuration...

I mean, if I open the doc with excel VBA, it doesn't update, if I open manually, it does update...

Comment: You can access the Range in Word headers and footers with `objDoc.Sections.Headers.Range` and `objDoc.Sections.Footers.Range`

Comment: Ok, I tried to use it, but I doesn't know much about that function, I googled it and found some people using "objDoc.Sections.Headers.Range.Select" but it didn't works for me, "The requested member of the collection does not exist."

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185230/add-header-and-footer-to-mulitpage-word-doc-vba/49188915#49188915

Answer (score 1):

I created a test document with a single page, header and footer, with the footer using the keyword "VAR_DATA". The example code below will search for all footers in the document and make the replacement. Notice that the code **only** searches in `Section(1)` though. If you have more sections, you may have to create an outer loop to search for each footer in every section.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FixMyFooter()
    Dim myWord As Object
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Set myWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set myDoc = myWord.Documents.Open("C:\Temp\footertest.docx")

    Dim footr As Word.HeaderFooter
    For Each footr In myDoc.Sections(1).Footers
        With footr.Range.Find
            .Text = "VAR_DATA"
            .Replacement.Text = Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yyyy")
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop
        End With
    Next footr

    myDoc.Save
    myWord.Quit
End Sub
```

You'll need to expand the example to find your additional text with your own formatting.